# Play framework clean vs clean-all

Tags: java, playframework, console, playframework-2.0

I'm using the play framework for java 
I would like to know what the console commands play clean and clean-all are doing? (is there any the difference?)

There is any reason to do play clean clean instead of play clean?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In first versions of Play 1.x there was command 'clean' it cleans temp files and bytecode cache. Later in 2.0 you can choose what directly clean by commands clean -cache, clean -files or clean -all. So clean and clean-all the same commands and acts the sameway. In newest versions you need call activator to clean project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So what is play clean is doing since 2.x? And there is any difference between play clean to play clean clean?